# Что делает данный код на языке Python?

Tags: python, массивы

Как я понял, есть некий массив в переменной `A`.
Я закинул в компилятор и оно просто переворачивает данный массив.

Но каким путем и зачем?
Каким образом происходит транспонирование?
И что делает каждая строка?

```
A = [ 
        [11, 12, 13, 14],
        [21, 22, 23, 24],
        [31, 32, 33, 34]
    ]

for row in zip(*A):
     print(*row)
```

Comment: Вам нужно почитать о списках, о цикле for, о функции zip, об операторе звездочка для распаковки итерируемых объектов... Да всё описание языка, короче, читайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) берёт на вход несколько списков и создаёт из них zip-объект (списки, если Python2) кортежей...

Первый элемент полученного списка содержит кортеж из первых элементов всех списков-аргументов, второй элемент - кортеж из вторых элементов и т.д.

Сначала вы инициализируете список списков (А), потом просите для каждого элемента "прозипованного А" сделать print.

Answer (score 2):

```
A=("Привет", "Пока")
B=("мир!", "Шарлота!")

for item in zip(A, B):
    print(item)
```

```
A=\
[[11, 12, 13, 14],         
 [21, 22, 23, 24],
 [31, 32, 33, 34]]

#for item in zip(*A):
# Эквивалентно:
#for row in zip(A[0], A[1], A[2]):
for COLUMN in zip(A[0], A[1], A[2]):
    #print(*COLUMN)
    # Эквивалентно:
    print(COLUMN[0], COLUMN[1], COLUMN[2])
# Имя row путает и совершенно неправильно.
# В данном случае COLUMN - это столбец матрицы A.
```

Что происходит?

1. Распаковка аргументов.
   Почитайте о операторе распаковки (звездочка).
2. Применение zip с аргументами строки матрицы.

Аналогом без zip было бы:

```
for column_index in range(4):
    column=[row[column_index] for row in A]
    print(*column)
```